# ActiveRecord Timedate Column Update all to NULL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I am trying to update a timedate column to NULL and I can't get it to work. Please help.

I tried:

```
User.where(interviewed: false).where("interview_date < ?", Time.now).update_all(interview_date: NULL)
```

I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant NULL
```

I tried:

```
User.where(interviewed: false).where("interview_date < ?", Time.now).update_all(interview_date: null)
```

I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `null' for main:Object
```

I tried:

```
User.where(interviewed: false).where("interview_date < ?", Time.now).update_all(interview_date: "")
```

I get:

```
PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""
```

Comment: Have you tried: `interview_date: 'NULL'`? http://forums.devshed.com/postgresql-help-21/insert-null-values-date-field-postgresql-877227.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `NULL` type in Ruby. Only [`nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html).

You must to do it like this:

```
User.where(interviewed: false).where("interview_date < ?", Time.now).update_all(interview_date: nil)
```

ActiveRecord will convert ruby's nil to sql null for you automatically.